# AppEnginge JAVA SetOrdering Funaction is not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

AppEnginge JAVA SetOrdering Funaction is not working

Messages.java

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Messages{

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Persistent
String name;

@Persistent
String Comments;

@Persistent
Date addedDate;
```

Query is

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Messages.class);
query.setOrdering("addedDate desc");
List<Messages> results = (List<Messages>) query.execute();
```

also added indexing

```
<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="false">
<datastore-index kind="Messages" ancestor="true">
<property name="addedDate"  direction="desc" />
</datastore-index>
```

Result is not coming as expected.order by the addedDate.It results random data not ordered by addedDate Please Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the index definition for "Messages". You don't need to define an index on a single property.

Try without an index definition for Messages. You should get the correct results.

Comment: removed the index definition and cleaned the old indexing using vaccuume_indexes but resuting the same :(

Comment: The code you posted here is correct. If you still see a problem, it must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Yes It was my mistake.. i was stored the result in HashSet thats why the result was coming random